# Apache mod-rewrite 1 single image to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 domains that essentially point to the same virtualhost directory on the server running apache. Therefore:

`foobar.com/images/booya.png` is the same file as `boofar.com/images/booya.png`

I would like the 2 to be different images, for example:

`boofar.com/images/booya.png` to serve `images/booya2.png` instead.

I don't believe this is acheivable with a 301 but seems like it should be doable with a `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear about the question but probably this should work for you in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?boofar\.com$
RewriteRule ^(images)/booya\.png$ /$1/booya2.png [L,R]
```